# How to get Access_Token after authenticating with ionic cloud

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cloud

I am using ionic cloud for Authentication, I am able to authenticate with `LinkedIn` and `Google`, now I need to call some api, which they need access token, but value of access token is undefined,

`this.user.social.linkedin.access_token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ionic support answer:

> using Ionic Auth there is no way to get access to the Linkedin auth access token at this time. You're limited to the data we fetch from those providers and return to you.